# How to add a user control drop down property in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am using a class library in [Visual Basic 2010 Express Edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express#Visual_Basic_Express) to make a custom textbox control. How do I add a dropdown property for the textbox?

I need a dynamic dropdown menu not like when you using

```
Enum MaxValue
   item1 = 0
End Enum
```

because I have to get the items from the database.

I tried adding a browsable option but nothing happened:

```
<Browsable(True)>
Property Max_Value() As String

     Get
        Return MaxValue
     End Get

     Set(value As String
        MaxValue = value
     End Set
End Property
```

Comment: It sounds like you're after a ComboBox not a TextBox. There are plenty of tutorials online for this. Google 'vb.net how to populate a combo box from a database'

Comment: Thanks FloatingKiwi for your replay

Comment: but i'm About to make a custom user control and adding some property what i need is adding a drop-down property list to let the user select the value from the list

Comment: Are you asking for a design time drop down? This article may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760544/visual-studio-design-time-property-form-list-drop-down

Comment: thanks alot 
but this code in c# is there any thing else using vb.net

Comment: @Eng.Chmai You can use the code converter : http://converter.telerik.com/ . There are many others

Answer (score 1):

```
    Imports System.ComponentModel
    Imports System.Drawing.Design
    Imports System.Windows.Forms.Design

    Public Class TestTextBox
            Inherits TextBox

            <Browsable(True)>
            <Editor(GetType(Editor), GetType(UITypeEditor))>
            <DefaultValue("Hello")>
            Public Property MyProperty As String

            Private Class Editor
                    Inherits UITypeEditor

                    Private mSvc As IWindowsFormsEditorService

                    Public Overrides Function GetEditStyle(context As ITypeDescriptorContext) As UITypeEditorEditStyle
                            Return UITypeEditorEditStyle.DropDown
                    End Function

                    Public Overrides Function EditValue(context As ITypeDescriptorContext, provider As IServiceProvider, value As Object) As Object
                            mSvc = CType(provider.GetService(GetType(IWindowsFormsEditorService)), IWindowsFormsEditorService)

                            Dim lb As New ListBox()
                            For Each value In {"Hello", "Whats", "Happening"}
                                    lb.Items.Add(value)
                            Next

                            If value IsNot Nothing Then
                                    lb.SelectedItem = value
                            End If

                            mSvc.DropDownControl(lb)

                            value = DirectCast(lb.SelectedItem, String)

                            Return value
                    End Function

            End Class

    End Class
```

Comment: thanks a lot :))
i'll try this 
i see what i need in this is code, thanks for replay again